# How do you reset your eclipse browser to start a new homework assignment?

Tags: eclipse

I'm starting to learn eclipse and just got through the first set of hw that was the Hello world exercise. I'm moving on to the next assignment but the Hello world file is still there and when I run the new assignment for the code i just get Hello world. Is there any way to start a fresh new file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to create a new Eclipse project take a look here:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs302/labs/EclipseTutorial/Step_02.html

If you are looking for how to delete a file from Eclipse:

- Right click the file in `Package Explorer` and select `Delete`, the choose `Ok`

Let me know if you need to know anything else concerning this question and let me know if I misunderstood you and didn't properly address your question.